# Break async / wait declaration chain in Dart

Tags: dart, asynchronous, async-await

I wonder if you can escape the async / wait chain in Dart. AFAIK every time you want to make a sync call to an async function you must use **await** but this forces you to make the function which holds the instruction to become async too.

Here is an example:

```dart
Future<String> helloAsync() async{
  return Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2), ()=>'Hello');
}

void helloSync(){
  //call helloAsync synchronously (somehow without making this function async)
  //print returned value
}

void main(){
  helloSync();
}
```

In here if I want to make a sync call to `helloAsync()` inside the `HellowSync()` I must add await like:

```dart
void helloSync(){
  String s = await helloAsync();
  print(s);
}
```

but this will not work until I add the **async** keyword for it - and if I do this means that I have to do it for `main()` function too.

Is there a way to break this chain of **async** / **await** declaration?
(In the initial example this would mean no async declaration for main function)

Comment: If the callers of your asynchronous functions don't need to wait until they complete, the callers either can choose to not wait for them or the function can choose to return `void` instead of a `Future`.  Otherwise, if callers need to wait for an asynchronous function to complete, that inherently means that the callers must be asynchronous too.

Comment: @jamesdlin (in general) If a caller needs to wait for an async function to complete it does not make the caller async - it simply "forces" or "wait" for the async to wait - making the caller to look as a sync function that might take a while to complete. There is a difference between a  sync/async behavior and sync/async syntax and architecture.

Comment: From an API perspective, yes, you can make an asynchronous function look like a synchronous function if there's a mechanism to block while it's waiting.  Dart does not provide any supported mechanism to do that, and such mechanisms are often error-prone.

Comment: Dart is single-threaded (per isolate). There is no way for a function to delay returning a value until an asynchronous operation has completed. The function must *synchronously* return a result before any asynchronous computation can proceed. That's why a function which needs to wait on an asynchronous computation must itself be asynchronous - otherwise it will block the asynchronous computation from ever completing, since control won't return to the event loop.

Comment: @jamesdlin As much as I can understand why is error-prone the fact that I have no liberty on that matter saddens me a little.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [.then()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Future/then.html) instead. You can't return the result of a Future from a synchronous function, but since your helloSync() returns void anyway, .then() might be what you are looking for.

```
void helloSync(){
  helloAsync().then((result) => print(result));
}
```

Comment: Using `.then()` is not any better than using `await`.  The above code is equivalent to `void helloSync() async { var result = await helloAsync(); print(result); }`

Comment: I'd recommend using await over .then() but he asked how to do it without making the method async and that's not possible with await.

Comment: Again, it's no different from the code from my comment.  Using the `async` keyword enables the `await` keyword.  What makes a function asynchronous is not the `async` keyword but whether it returns a `Future`, and `async` functions can choose to return `void`.

Comment: There is a difference if you add a third line of code below print(result). Using .then() does not block the execution of that line while await does. If you remove the await, in his code, you can't print the result. I have no idea why he doesn't want to use async/await and I'm pretty sure that there is a better solution for his problem though (like moving print() into helloAsync()).